# "does there exist" or "does there exists"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I have seen many uses, even in books, of the three words "does there exist" and of the three words "does there exists". Examples:

> - **Does there exist** a political business cycle? [[1]](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00127721)
> - **Does there exists** a general procedure for justifying ... [[2]](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=rqo1qLr41nYC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq="does+there+exists"&source=bl&ots=tO9CEs11ki&sig=NyLWC_UhuUQwGuVeoDsdJH77oZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS9ui90rbMAhWBB8AKHas9DDs4FBDoAQgiMAI#v=onepage&q="does%20there%20exists"&f=false)

And even in the same paragraph in another book:

> **Does there exists** a uniform way of specifying languages ...? That is, **does there exist** a uniform construction such that ...? [[3]](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=CLPiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq="does+there+exist"+"does+there+exists"&source=bl&ots=BYs54MOpOE&sig=a3QY0Y6z2TPpJr4OEwbpgWsYsL8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQtaTK0bbMAhUBNxQKHdeGD_8Q6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q="does%20there%20exist"%20"does%20there%20exists"&f=false)

I would guess that the form *does there exist* is the right one, but a confirmation would be nice, or even better -- an explanation/reference.

Comment: The presence of the dummy auxiliary verb "do" means that the main verb must be in the plain (infinitival) form, i.e. "exist".

Comment: Except for a handful of books by non-native English speakers, this mistake seems to have come into existence only after the invention of word-processing software. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Does+there+exists%2Cdoes+there+exists&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDoes%20there%20exists%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20there%20exists%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I think that Ronald V. Book *is* a native English speaker... but thanks for the Ngram!

Answer (score 4):

You can have singular and plural, but like this:

> Does there exist a polical business cycle?
>   Do there exist political business cycles?

But (as BillJ said) both keep the infinitive form "exist".